# jar file not identified by android project with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have a local file `{projectroot}/libs/javacsv.jar`

and I include it in my build.gradle which is also in the root of my project as following

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

however when i compile my project I still get

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myproject'.  No such
>   property: compile for class:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

how can i fix this i just want to compile my android project with my libs dir :/

Comment: Does your "build.gradle" have "apply plugin: 'java'" or "apply plugin: 'groovy'"?

Comment: Are these libs dependencies for build script or for android application? There are two dependencies sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two dependencies sections in `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    //repositories for build script dependencies
    }

   dependencies {
   //dependencies for build script
   }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
//repositories for project dependencies
}

android {
....
}

dependencies {
//dependencies for project 
}
```

So move your libs section to correct one.